# Meteor and Reactjs component loading on demand

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I'm starting a large scale app and need advise on setting up the folder structure and all. So I'm not sure if on Meteor startup if it loads all of the components to one file or not ( if all the components are in the client/ folder )

If it does not load all the components and send it to the client initially the this question has been answered. if Meteor do send all the components to the browser then need a way to fix it.

At the moment I have like 70 components and do not wanna send all of this to the user on the initial page load.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though incremental/on-demand loading for components is in the 'todo'/'future feature' stage.

From - [Trello: Meteor Roadmap](https://trello.com/c/24s6vyxo/55-incremental-loading)

> Right now, on initial pageload, you download all of the JavaScript,
>   templates, and css in the app.
>
> This task is to make it so that you download just the parts that you
>   need. You might download additional parts in the background, or
>   on-demand as you navigate through the app. (To be clear, this would
>   apply to the JavaScript, CSS, and templates, not to database contents,
>   which would continue to be handled by the subscription system.)
>
> It should be possible to secure some of the additional parts so that
>   only certain users can download them. For example, only admin users
>   could download the JavaScript and templates for the admin console.
>
> Related: when the app is updated, only download the changed parts, not
>   the whole app.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer.. is this a possible solution ? https://github.com/jedwards1211/meteor-webpack-react

Comment: @Sahan it looks like webpack would make it more efficient for the client/server, but would not be the incremental / on-demand you are looking for. I think it would be a good alternative until Meteor gets to the todo i mentioned.